# How to handle this XML data?

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML file:

```
<images>
<photo image="images/101.jpg" colorboxImage="images/101.jpg" colorboxInfo="Item 01" colorboxClass="image" url = "http://www.flashxml.net" target="_blank">
<![CDATA[<head>Hello</head><body>Welcome to the new Circular Gallery</body>]]></photo>

<photo image="images/102.jpg" colorboxImage="images/102.jpg" colorboxInfo="Item 02" colorboxClass="image" url = "http://www.flashxml.net" target="_blank">
<![CDATA[<head>Download the new Circular Gallery</head><body>for FREE</body>]]></photo>

<photo image="images/103.jpg" colorboxImage="images/103.jpg" colorboxInfo="Item 03" colorboxClass="image" url = "http://www.flashxml.net" target="_blank">
<![CDATA[<head>Insert it in your website</head><body>without any special skills or software</body>]]></photo>

<photo image="images/104.jpg" colorboxImage="images/104.jpg" colorboxInfo="Item 04" colorboxClass="image" url = "http://www.flashxml.net" target="_blank">
<![CDATA[<head>Put your own images in the "images" folder</head><body>and update the images.xml file accordingly</body>]]></photo>

<photo image="images/105.jpg" colorboxImage="images/105.jpg" colorboxInfo="Item 05" colorboxClass="image" url = "http://www.flashxml.net" target="_blank">
<![CDATA[<head>You can put <a href="http://www.flashxml.net" target="_blank">links</a> in this HTML/CSS formatted text</head><body>and you can also put links behind the images</body>]]></photo></images>
```

and this PHP code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("images.xml");

foreach ($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo "Child node: " . $child . "<br />" . $child["image"] . "<br />";

  }
```

and I get results like this:

```
Child node: HelloWelcome to the new Circular Gallery
images/101.jpg
Child node: Download the new Circular Galleryfor FREE
images/102.jpg
Child node: Insert it in your websitewithout any special skills or software
images/103.jpg
```

I want to separate text in this part:

```
<![CDATA[<head>You can put <a href="http://www.flashxml.net" target="_blank">links</a> in this HTML/CSS formatted text</head><body>and you can also put links behind the images</body>]]>
```

I want to read the text in the head part and the body part but this code will combine them in one text, and I couldn't know how to get each one and do what I need to do with it

Comment: It's a CDATA section. Anything within that is treated as a literal string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to parse again the node content (using [simplexml_load_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)). But I found no function in [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) to retrieve the node's text content, only child elements. Strange.

But it looks like conversion to string of a node returns this node's content, thus you could try this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("images.xml");

foreach ($xml->children() as $child)
{
   echo "Child node: " . $child . "<br />" . $child["image"] . "<br />";
   $content = simplexml_load_string("<dummy>". $child . "</dummy>");
   echo "child head: " . $content->head . "<br/>";
   echo "child body: " . $content->body . "<br/>";
}
```